# C# SQL Query continous return of result

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I don't have any code cause I don't know where to start with this and Google has not helped me with this one, let me explain.
If I use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and execute a query which takes a significant amount of time it returns the rows continuously until the query has finished.
I want to achieve the same result in C# as I have a web page that queries a database which can take some minutes to finish and instead for the users having to wait until the whole query has finished they could have this "incremental" result being displayed on the web page.

Comment: If the query really is taking a long time, my first thought would be to try and improve the performance of the query.

Comment: You could implement some sort of pagination, instead of returning everything.

Comment: `SqlDataReader` can and does read results incrementally as they're produced, no problem -- in fact, SSMS is just another .NET application that does just this. If you have an ORM framework wrapped around this that insists on getting all the results before it returns, that could complicate things. Ditto if you have to incorporate incremental results of the query into incremental rendering of your web page. The details depend on the frameworks used. To a first approximation, as others have said, reducing what the query actually returns is usually easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement pagination in your queries and then use an advanced datagrid component to load the data while scrolling. Telerik could do something like that or you could create your own. E.g. https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/performance/virtualization/defaultcs.aspx